# How to use DE suppression list in the journey builder?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio

I created a journey in Journey Builder, and I have a suppression list in my data extension. However, when attempting to utilize the suppression list from the data extension, I encountered an issue as there is no option available to include the suppression list from the data extension.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use suppression list in journey builder send, use [Exclusion Script](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000384149&type=1) in the journey email activity instead.

1. In your journey, click on the Email Activity and select the Email
2. Select the Delivery Options tab on the left to see the 'Exclusion Script' option.

Here is a sample script checking if email address exists in a referenced data extension

```
ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("Exclusion_DATA_EXTENSION_NAME","EMAIL_ADDR_FIELD_NAME", EMAILADDR))>0
```